# Simplest/Effective approach of calling back a method from a lib file

Tags: c++, callback, c++98

I am currently calling some methods from an external lib file. Is there a way for these methods to callback functions in my application once they are done as these methods might be running in separate threads?
The following diagram shows what I am trying to achieve

[image]

I wanted to know what is the best way of sending a message back to the calling application ? Any boost components that might help ?

Comment: A lib file is just an collection of object files (read: TUs). So unless you have ABI differences, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Once the threads are done i would like them to call back a method in my calling application how can I do that ?

Comment: Not how. Yes you can do that.

Comment: Oh well. Let me post something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** after the edit:

It's not clear what you have. Do you control the thread entry point for the thread started by the external library (this would surprise me)?

Assuming:

- the library function accepts a callback
- assuming you don't control the source for the library function, not the thread function started by this library function in a background thread
- you want to have the callback processed on the original thread

you could have the callback store an record in some kind of queue that you regularly check from the main thread (no busy loops, of course). Use a *lock-free* queue, or synchronize access to the queue using e.g. a `std::mutex`.

**Update** Here's such a queuing version **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95ba750477c79a51)** as well:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// fake external library taking a callback
extern void library_function(int, void(*cb)(int,int));

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// our client code
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

void callback_handler(int i, int input)
{
    static std::mutex mx;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
    std::cout << "Callback #" << i << " from task for input " << input << "\n";
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// callback queue
#include <deque>
#include <future>

namespace {
    using pending_callback = std::packaged_task<void()>;
    std::deque<pending_callback> callbacks;
    std::mutex callback_mutex;

    int process_pending_callbacks() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(callback_mutex);

        int processed = 0;
        while (!callbacks.empty()) {
            callbacks.front()();
            ++processed;
            callbacks.pop_front();
        }

        return processed;
    }

    void enqueue(pending_callback cb) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(callback_mutex);
        callbacks.push_back(std::move(cb));
    }
}

// this wrapper to "fake" a callback (instead queuing the real
// callback_handler)
void queue_callback(int i, int input)
{
    enqueue(pending_callback(std::bind(callback_handler, i, input)));
}

int main()
{
    // do something with delayed processing:
    library_function(3, queue_callback);
    library_function(5, queue_callback);

    // wait for completion, periodically checking for pending callbacks
    for (
        int still_pending = 3 + 5; 
        still_pending > 0; 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10))) // no busy wait
    {
        still_pending -= process_pending_callbacks();
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// somewhere, in another library:
void library_function(int some_input, void(*cb)(int,int))
{
    std::thread([=] {
        for (int i = 1; i <= some_input; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 5000)); // TODO abolish rand()
            cb(i, some_input);
        }
    }).detach();
}
```

Typical output:

```
Callback #1 from task for input 5
Callback #2 from task for input 5
Callback #1 from task for input 3
Callback #3 from task for input 5
Callback #2 from task for input 3
Callback #4 from task for input 5
Callback #5 from task for input 5
Callback #3 from task for input 3
```

Note that

- output is interspersed for both worker threads
- but because the `callbacks` queue is FIFO, the sequence of callbacks per worker thread is preserved

---

This is what I thought of, before you edited the question: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26013c5db34c473e)**

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

extern int library_function(bool);

static std::vector<std::thread> workers; // TODO implement a proper pool

void await_workers()
{
    for(auto& th: workers)
        if (th.joinable()) th.join();
}

template <typename F, typename C>
void do_with_continuation(F f, C continuation)
{
    workers.emplace_back([=] () mutable {
            auto result = f();
            continuation(result);
        });
}

#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

void callback(int result)
{
    static std::mutex mx;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
    std::cout << "Resulting value from callback " << result << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    // do something with delayed processing:
    do_with_continuation(std::bind(library_function, false), callback);
    do_with_continuation(std::bind(library_function, true),  callback);

    await_workers();
}

// somewhere, in another library:

#include <chrono>
int library_function(bool some_input)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(some_input? 6 : 3));
    return some_input ? 42 : 0;
}
```

It will always print the output in the order:

```
Resulting value from callback 0
Resulting value from callback 42
```

Notes:

- make sure you synchronize access to shared state from within such a callback (in this case, `std::cout` is protected by a lock)
- you'd want to make a thread pool, instead of an ever-growing vector of (used) threads

Comment: Added a demo of the queuing approach too, compliments of the house.